# Using Apache REDIRECT_STATUS to allow custom ErrorDocument

Tags: apache, cgi, access-control, errordocument

I have an Apache config that uses legacy access rules and CGI error documents.

```
ErrorDocument 403 /perl/dispay.pl?page=error403

SetEnvIf User-Agent "SomeOldUserAgent" badUA
Deny from env=badUA
```

The blocking of the user agent works fine, but unfortunately the Deny rule also covers the generating of the error page.

I would like to exclude the error page from the blocking to provide a dynamic error message.

I have tried to allow by REDIRECT_STATUS, but this doesn't work.

```
SetEnvIf REDIRECT_STATUS 403 errorPage
Allow from env=errorPage
```

Any ideas ?